# Training hyperspectral data using Tensorflow & Keras

Tags: csv, dataframe, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, keras

I am looking for an approach to train a hyperspectral image data on Tensorflow.
The training sample is encoded in CSV and has an arbitrary x-y dimension but constant depth:
The data looks like this:

*Sample1.csv*: **50x4x220** (Row 1-50 is supposed to be aligned with row 51-100, 101-150, and 151-200)
*Sample2.csv*: **18x71x220** (Row 1-18 is supposed to be aligned with row 19-36, etc.)
*Sample3.csv*: **33x41x220** (same as above)
....
*Sample100.csv*: **15x8x220** (same as above)

Is there any project example that I can use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, show the format of your files.

Comment: @DanielMöller: Sorry what do you mean with the format of the files? You mean the preview? If that's what you mean, it's here: https://prnt.sc/qrs1yh

Comment: What is your problem, classification, location or segmentation?

Comment: @DanielMöller: Long term it would be localization of certain image segment. But short term, it would be easier to classify using sliding patch - e.g. divide a large image of 2048x2048x220 into a patch of 128x128x220. The reason to do this is because I do not have a resource to train 2048x2048x220 at once. Ideally I would like to have YOLO, but with my small GPU this is just unbearable. Any suggestion?

Comment: YOLOs are one of the models I have no experience with :( -- If it was classification it would be fairly easy. For segmentation you should probably use some padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [survey on DL algorithms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.10674.pdf) used to classify hyperspectral datas.

Since you have datas or varying size, you will have to create patches of datas, you won't be able to feed datas of different sizes.

For example you could feed patches of `(16, 16, 220)` to your network.

I worked on a CNN with images of multispectral bands, I had less bands that you have, the size of patches was obviously important, I used a UNET in image segmentation.

Edit with an example using`(None, None, 220)` as input :

```py
model = Sequential()

# this applies 32 convolution filters of size 3x3 each.
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(None, None, 220)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# model.add(Flatten())
# Replace flatten by GlobalPooling example :
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D()) 
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

adam = Adam(lr=1e-4)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam)
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean patches of data? Do you mean zero-padding so that all file sizes have the same size?

Comment: Patches as a sub-array of your array. for example a 40x40x220 array could be divided to a number of 5x5x220 patches. Then your network will be able to segment any kind of dataset as long as you shrink it to 5x5x220 patches. It's useful when you have different type of datas

Comment: Did it work for you? Usually dividing it into smaller sub-patches is not a good idea because it could have continuity between the sub-patches - it's like dividing person's face for face recognition. During testing eventually the network would probably only recognize the half of it. What kind of images are you working with? Is it chemical data on the surface / satellite images / ...?

Comment: It "is" possible to use different sizes. (Though very hard for segmentation purposes)

Comment: @DanielMöller How would you do it? I would go for either padding or patching? user2754279 It worked for me in my case of segmentation since you classify pixels. But you are right if you want to classify the whole image, padding is probably better, patching can be done but won't be as efficient

Comment: Input shapes should be `(None, None, 220)` and instead of `Flatten` you use one of the possible GlobalPooling layers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I never tried smth like that, good to know

Comment: @DanielMöller: Sorry what does it mean: (None, None, 220) -> What does 'None' significally does?

Comment: In your input tensor of your model you define the shape as `(None, None, 220)`, the model will then take whatever shape as long as there is 220 as channel. `inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((None, None, 220))` if you prefer

Comment: @OrpheeFaucoz: Is there an equivalent for (None, None, 220) in Keras? The thing is I am only using TF as a backend - my code is wrapped in Keras. Normally Keras hat its own layers and we typically defined this as: model = Sequential()

Comment: I wrote the code using tf 2.0 that embed Keras layers, I'll post an edit on my post with keras standalone with `Sequential`

Comment: @user2754279 You'll also need to replace `Flatten()` by a GlobalPooling as Daniel said

Comment: @OrpheeFaucoz: Ah yes, perfect! Now it works. Thank you!